# What is the most pythonic way of replacing values in nested lists?

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I have a list of strings, and I want to replace each `'X'` and `'O'` with `True` and `False` - turning each string into a list of booleans.

```
arr = ['XOOXO',
       'XOOXO',
       'OOOXO',
       'XXOXO',
       'OXOOO']

temp_list = []
bool_lists =[]

for str in arr:
    for char in str:
        if char == "X":
            temp_list.append(True)
        else:
            temp_list.append(False)
    bool_lists.append(temp_list)
    temp_list = []
```

This fills up the `temp_list` variable with booleans, appends the `temp_list` to the `bool_lists` variable, then empties the `temp_list` variable before starting on the next row.

The code above works, but I feel like there must be a more straightforward, pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: Example: `bools = [c == "X" for c in "XOOXO"]` yields `[True, False, False, True, False]`. Extend for the `arr` list.

Comment: `bool_lists = [[char == 'X' for char in string] for string in arr]`

Comment: See the linked duplicate. Problems like this are a natural fit for list comprehensions. Use the technique twice: for the code the produces a "row" of booleans from a single string, and again to apply that code to each string in the overall list.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I knew it probably had to do something with dict/list comprehension, and I looked around but couldn’t find it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like so:

```
dct = {'X': True, 'O': False}
bool_lists = [[dct[c] for c in s] for s in arr]
print(bool_lists)
# [[True, False, False, True, False], [True, False, False, True, False], [False, False, False, True, False], [True, True, False, True, False], [False, True, False, False, False]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it's more sample

```
[[{"X":True,"O":False}.get(col, col)  for col in row] for row in arr]
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to check out the `.get()` method thanks for bringing that to my attention.